# What is validity in terms of PGP 6.5.8?

Tags: pgp, gnupg

In PGP 6.5.8, there is a concept of "validity" for a key, and it shows in the user interface for each key on the keyring.

What is this concept, and how to you set it so a key is considered valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PGP (and also GnuPG) uses the concept of a web of trust to allow you to validate the ownership of other's keys, also if you didn't meet them in person.

### PGP's Trust Model

A long explanation is in [PGP's manual, starting from *checking trust*](http://www.pgpi.org/doc/pgpintro/#p18). The short version:

In PGP, a key is valid, if

- it is not revoked or expired
- it is your own key (which is also implicitly trusted) or
- it is certified (signed) by other valid and trusted keys, requiring at least either

  - one certification by a fully trusted key or
  - two certifications by different marginally trusted keys.

Certifications are shared on key servers and show that the issuer is sure about the signee's identity. Trust is only locally (by yourself) and not shared, and defines whose certifications you trust for validating other's keys.

#### Trust example

Alice certified Bob's key, and fully trusts Bob. Bob certified Carol. As Alice key is valid (it's her own key), Bob's key is also valid (signed by another valid, trusted key), so keys certified by him are again considered valid for Alice, here Carol's key.

### GnuPG's Trust Model

GnuPG has a [very similar trust model](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x334.html), but by default requires certifications by three marginally trusted participants (or like PGP one by a fully trusted key), and limits the length of trust paths to five (allowing a maximum of four intermediate certifications).

Comment: There's trust and validity.  While trust is an important part of a valid certificate, it's not the only factor.  Validity is determined by certificate expiration, state of revocation, and verifying the identity of said certificate.

Comment: Indeed, this should be included. Thank you for giving a note on this.